# ajax response returns every value as a single character

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to figure out where I go wrong in this request. I have an ajax post request and I receive the response as single character. For example instead of "name":"john" I get:
n
a
m
e
j
o
h
n
This is my code:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'test.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: ({
            name: 'john'
        }),
        success: function(data) {
            var JSONString = data;
            var JSONObject = JSON.parse(JSONString);
            console.log(JSONString);
            load(JSONString);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
}

<?php
$db = new SQLite3('database.db');
$userAnswer = $_POST['name']; 

$results= $db->query("SELECT * FROM 'database' where name='".$userAnswer."'");

$data= [];
while ($res= $results->fetchArray(1))
{
array_push($data, $res);
}
echo json_encode($data);

?>
function load(res) {
    var JSONObject = res;
    var arr = Object.values(JSONObject);
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Calling `Object.values(string)` will split your string into an array of characters.

Comment: @RyanWilson, but even looping without Object.values(string) gives me the same result.

Comment: @patofka Looping a string value is like looping an array of characters.

Comment: @RyanWilson, yes, I know :) I just can not find the. solution, I am stuck.

Comment: I am sorry if I was not clear enough. I need the full values in array [ {name: "john"} ,  {name: "john"} ] and not as single characters.

Comment: @patofka Why do you need the same key value pair twice?

Comment: @RyanWilson, it was just an example. The values will be unique.

Comment: @patofka You are passing the json string into your function, pass in `JSONObject` not `JSONString`, call it like `load(JSONObject)`

Comment: @RyanWilson, thank you so much, I was going crazy!

Comment: You're welcome. I have voted to close this post as it was caused by a typo